# Data inserts the last array only in a Laravel app

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a list of days for this month. But the problem is when I insert or add the data it only entered the last array or data from the list. For example, I add `Jan-02-2019,` and it will then insert `Jan-31-2019`.

**Controller**

```php
public function insertSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $employeeTimeSet = new Schedule;
    $employeeTimeSet->employee_no = $request->input('hidEmployeeno');
    $employeeTimeSet->last_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeLast');
    $employeeTimeSet->first_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst');
    $employeeTimeSet->date_today = $request->input('dateToday');
    $employeeTimeSet->time_in = $request->input('timeIn');
    $employeeTimeSet->time_out = $request->input('timeOut');
    $employeeTimeSet->save();
}
```

Here are the view and form:

```php
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <small>Employee No. and Name:</small>
        <b><i> {{ $employee->employee_no }} : {{ $employee->last_name }}, {{ $employee->first_name }}</i></b>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeno" value='<?php echo $employee->employee_no ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeLast" value='<?php echo $employee->last_name ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeFirst" value='<?php echo $employee->first_name ?>'>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
@php
    $today = today(); 
    $dates = []; 

    for($i=1; $i < $today->daysInMonth + 1; ++$i) {
        $dates[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, $i)->format('F-d-Y');
    }
@endphp

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DATE TODAY</th>
        <th>TIME IN</th>
        <th>TIME OUT</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($dates as $date)
        <tr>
            <td><b>{{ $date }}</b></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="dateToday" value="{{ $date }}">
            <td><input type="time" name="timeIn" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="timeOut" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
            <td>{{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-clock">&nbsp;&nbsp;SET TIME</i>',['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',  'style'=>"display: inline-block;"])}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: @KarlHill: thanks for editing here. In general, if you encounter niceties or politenesses, such as "please help me" and variations thereof, you can just remove them. Anything that is not germane to the question can go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of the way you structured your HTML form. If I understood your question correctly, the following should make it work:

```
@php
    $today = today(); 
    $dates = []; 
    for($i=1; $i < $today->daysInMonth + 1; ++$i) {
        $dates[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($today->year, $today->month, $i)->format('F-d-Y');
    }
@endphp
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <small>Employee No. and Name:</small>
        <b><i> {{ $employee->employee_no }} : {{ $employee->last_name }}, {{ $employee->first_name }}</i></b>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DATE TODAY</th>
        <th>TIME IN</th>
        <th>TIME OUT</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($dates as $date)
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
            <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeno" value="{{ $employee->employee_no }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeLast" value="{{ $employee->last_name }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeFirst" value="{{ $employee->first_name }}">
            <tr>
                <td><b>{{ $date }}</b></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="dateToday" value="{{ $date }}">
                <td><input type="time" name="timeIn" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
                <td><input type="time" name="timeOut" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
                <td>{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-clock">&nbsp;&nbsp;SET TIME</i>',['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',  'style'=>"display: inline-block;"]) }}</td>
            </tr>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sir can you please explain why is the form the problm? tho there is an array right?

Comment: sir thank you again . one last problem is i cannot insert or add the first array or data which is `January-01-2019`

Comment: Please highlight the changes and explain them such that the OP can learn what was wrong and how you solved the problem